# Error when creating config parameter in bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I obtained this error when I want to create a config paramter to a bundle.

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "mrc_morales_tyre"

This is the code:

app/config/config.yml

```
mrc_morales_tyre:
    db_driver: orm
```

Configuration.php

```
    namespace MrcMorales\TyreBundle\DependencyInjection;

    use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
    use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

    /**
     * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
     *
     * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
     */
    class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
        {
            $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
            $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('mrc_morales_tyre');

            $supportedDrivers = array('orm');

            $rootNode
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('db_driver')
                        ->validate()
                            ->ifNotInArray($supportedDrivers)
                            ->thenInvalid('The driver %s is not supported. Please choose one of '.json_encode($supportedDrivers))
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end();

            return $treeBuilder;        

}
}
```

TyreExtension.php

```
namespace MrcMorales\TyreBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor;


/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class TyreExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();

        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    }
}
```

TyreBundle.php

```
namespace MrcMorales\TyreBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use MrcMorales\TyreBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ValidationPass;

class TyreBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new ValidationPass());
    }
}
```

ValidationPass is to load validation.yml in not usual folder and it works.

Thanks

Comment: Very strange... have you enabled the bundle in the AppKernel Class correctly?

Comment: yea!             new MrcMorales\TyreBundle\TyreBundle(),

Comment: Can you show us your Bundle.php file? (the one at the root of your bundle)

Comment: Seems alright... Can you add your config (the file where you put the `mrc_morales_tyre` configuration) please? That's strange, looks like the DI can't match your config with your bundle

Comment: yea, I edited again..

Comment: Resolved, see the below answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

Symfony by default expects than config var name is the name of extension, in this case tyre.

Then I need to change the Extension name to MrcMoralesTyreExtension but then we need override the method getContainerExtension() in:

TyreBundle.php

```
   public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        return new MrcMoralesTyreExtension();
    }
```